# How do I use the variable chosenDate(or any variable for that matter) out of the said scope

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

This is my code snippet:

```
  static DateTime chosenDate = DateTime.now();
  String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm').format(chosenDate);
  DateTime picked;
  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: chosenDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    if (picked != null && picked != chosenDate)
      setState(() {
        chosenDate = picked;
      });
  }
```

How do i ensure that the chosenDate can be used somewhere else, like an activity which displays chosenDate out of the said scope. I have declared it in the main.dart file as the following 
`DateTime chosenDate;`, but when I use it on another screen with the following statements, the value is returned as null with the error message saying that the getter 'year' was not found and hence a null is returned:

```
class _FinalPageState extends State<FinalPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("$formattedDate"),
    );
  }
}
```

Where formattedDate is `String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm').format(chosenDate);`

Also does anyone have any idea how to save this value such that with every app restart, it doesnt get lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State management such as `Provider` may help you. Look at this https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-pragmatic-state-management-using-provider-5c1129f9b5bb

you can simply use the `get` and `set` functions that are defined in `Provider` class to get or set the values.

```
class DateSelector {
  BuildContext context;
  final state;

  DateSelector(this.context) : state = Provider.of<AppState>(context);

  Future<Null> _selectDate() async {
    if (...) {
      //you may need to change picked as the format you like
      state.setChosenDate(picked);
    }
  }

}


class AppState with ChangeNotifier {
   String _date;

  getChosenDate() => _date;

  setChosenDate(d) {
    _date = d;
    notifyListeners();
  }}


//make sure the root class should be like
void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<AppState>(
        builder: (_) => AppState(),
        child: MaterialApp(
            home: HomePage(),
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false));
  }
}
```

//then simply call the get method to access it from any screen eg.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context);
   ....
   ....
     Text(appState.getChosenDate())
```

Comment: How does this work for Future<null/void> methods, does the await function still have to be present like before?